# Does jython have pep8 rules like python?

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.5

While browsing the web,i decided to pay the jython project a visit and read this news

> JyNI is a compatibility layer with the goal to enable Jython to use
>   native CPython extensions like NumPy or SciPy. This way we aim to
>   enable scientific Python code to run on Jython.
>   ...
>   Our philosophy is to integrate JyNI with Jython and CPython extensions
>   as seamless as possible. So JyNI aims to work without any
>   recompilation of Jython or the desired CPython extensions.

What it means is we can use NumPy or SciPy in jython.I have worked with python before but i lean more towards java.

Do python's pep 8 rules apply in jython?.

Comment: PEP 8 is a style guide for Python code. Python as in the language implemented by Jython among many others. What does C API compatibility have to do with this?

Comment: Python heads give me a headache.So vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEP8 is just a code style specification, albeit a very good one. You can use it on any Python implementation. It is widely used, but that doesn't mean your code won't work without it!